# What does ((short *)((((char *)(&arr[1]))+8))[3]=100; do?

Tags: c, pointers

```
...
    int arr[5];
    arr[3]=128;
    ((short *)((((char *)(&arr[1]))+8))[3]=100;
...
```

---

Above is part of a pretentious code.

1. What does

   ```
   ((short *)((((char *)(&arr[1])) + 8))[3] = 100
   ```

   the line do? The following is my thought assuming char is 1 byte and int is 4 byte.

   arr will look like `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`, `arr[3]`, `arr[4]` in memory with each 4 bytes. `&arr[1]` points to arr[1]. `(char *)(&arr[1])` is treating `arr[1]` value 4 bytes as char each of 1 byte.
2. What is the function part of `(char *)(&arr[1])` and `((char *)(&arr[1])) + 8` individually?

Comment: I think it is supposed to be `((short*)((char*)(&arr[1]) + 8))[3] = 100;` which would set the high-word in the last `int` to `00000000 01100100` and if the array were initialized to all zero (`int arr[5] = {0};`) would result in `a[4] = 6553600;` -- but with the declaration as is, and `a[4]` currently uninitialized,  it just results in *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: @user45765 The code is not useful and a bad example for future SO users.  Whatever, we disagree, but I won't resort to ad-hominem attacks:(

Comment: @MartinJames The code was copied from blackboard presentation from stanford youtube lecture part and I might have miss-copied things. The lecturer in the video did say it is bad code practice but it is worthwhile to understand what is going on. I would care less about attacks or down votes.

Comment: @user45765 umm.. you attacked me.  Note that the aim of SO is not primarily to teach or help you, but to help those who come after.  That is why I consider your question sub-prime.  I am aware that you care only about getting your answer, fine.

Comment: *The code was copied from blackboard presentation from stanford youtube lecture ... The lecturer in the video did say it is bad code practice but it is worthwhile to understand what is going on.* Those that can't do, teach? It's not useful to know what's going on with code like that - the code violates strict aliasing and is undefined behavior.  Nevermind it's objectively very hard to parse and completely unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((short *)((((char *)(&arr[1])) + 8))[3] = 100

&arr[1]:  is the address of the second int in arr (1*sizeof(int) from start).
((char *)(&arr[1])) : converts int address  to a char address
(((char *)(&arr[1])) + 8) : adds 8 bytes to the char address
((short *)((((char *)(&arr[1])) + 8)): converts the char address to a short address
((short *)((((char *)(&arr[1])) + 8))[3]: treats the short address as a beginning of an array of storts and goes to the third element in this array (3 * sizeof(short) bytes).
((short *)((((char *)(&arr[1])) + 8))[3] = 100; : assigns 100


*((short*)(((char*)arr) + 1*sizeof(int) + 8 + 3*sizeof(short))) = 100;
```

The size of an int varies depending on processors but is often 4 bytes.
The size of a short varies depending on processors but is often 2 bytes.

```
*((short*)(((char*)arr) + 18)) = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I see what it does now. It recast the int address type to char address and after that 8 is added as the char address.

Comment: The size of `short` can vary, too.  It is *at least* 16 bits, and very frequently it is exactly 16 bits, but it can be larger.  You can consider that to be part of the rationale for the fact that evaluation of expression in question produces undefined behavior (it violates the strict-aliasing rule).  FWIW, everything up to the "assigns 100" part of the explanation is right, though, as long as the alignment requirement for `short` does not exceed 8 bytes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger your right. When I wrote the answer my brain read float instead short. That is why in my original answer I had (float) casts. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's split it up (ignoring unneeded brackets):

```
int* p0 = &arr[1];
char* p1 = (char *)p0;
char* p2 = p1 + 8;
short* p3 = (short *)p2;
p3[3] = 100;
```

- Your `arr` array has 5 times an 4-bytes integer = a block of 20 bytes.
- `p0` points to the address of the second integer, so byte at index 4.
- `p1` stores `p0` as address to chars / bytes.
- `p2` increases the value of p1 by 8 (chars) = points to byte at index 12.
- `p3` changes p2 to pointer type of 2-bytes (short) integer.
- Last line points to fourth short (integer) value which means an address increment by 3 * 2 bytes = now we're at byte index 18 of `arr`. There we assign value 100 as the last two bytes (index 18 & 19) of our available memory.

In short:

```
((short *)arr)[9] = 100;
```

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf

int main(void) {
  // Initialize zero-filled memory
  int arr[5] = {0};
  // Write value 100 to last 2 bytes
  ((short*)arr)[9] = 100;
  // Print memory
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);  // 0 0 0 0 6553600
}
```

Comment: There is nothing to conclude on the program execution as the result is undefined. If you're lucky on 16 bit systems this will GPF, or do anything else. Results will be different on big and little endian archicteture. Architectures that are not byte addressable will also fail.

Answer (score 0):

it can be translated to:

```
short *ptr = (short *)(arr + 1 + 8 / sizeof(*arr)); // or &arr[1 + 8 / sizeof(*arr)]
ptr[3] = 100;
```

Comment: why DV? Any explanation